# WPF Application Update event

Tags: wpf, clr

In our developing app we have a 3d scene that contains our custom 3d objects.

Those objects need to have their Update function to get called each frame in order to update its internals like physics, logics and visual animation step

What would be a proper way to call this update queue each frame before the Window Content Rendered event is raised?

To be more clear I'm looking for something like

```
void ApplicationUpdateEvent(float time_delta)
{
   myObjectList.Update(float time_delta)
}
```

P.S. I know we can call it in the Window.ContentRendered event handler too, but we want to avoid it since wpf can implicitly raise ContentRendered event, for example, if one calls win32 MessageBox function somewhere in the code of other events handlers

Comment: You might take a look at the [CompositionTarget.Rendering event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.compositiontarget.rendering).

Comment: I'm sorry to not mention that, but we actually have it in CompositionTarget::Rendering event already. But in this context it performs same as Window.ContentRendered would. Whenever WPF implicitly raises rendering event - like when win32 MessageBox is called to show error - we get unexpected update of 3d objects, since CompositionTarget::Rendering is raised

Comment: I have a guess that we need to perform our own message loop in a separate thread in order to reach full control of updating objects and scene, but we wanted to avoid threading on the early development stage

Comment: "*Update function to get called each frame*" is exactly what CompositionTarget.Rendering is supposed to be used for. It seems you need to be more specific. Mayby you can just use a DispatcherTimer for the updates.